# How to correctly add constraints to the querybuilder node for CQ5 Reports

Tags: reporting, aem

I'm working on creating a custom report report page in CQ5. I've got my reportbase and columnbase components set up correctly, by following the steps listed [here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/developing-reports.html#Creating%20Your%20Own%20Report%20-%20An%20Example/). I am able to, for instance, pick up all the templates that are available, by setting the property `nodeTypes` to `cq:Template`

I want to add a constraint to it, say for example pick up templates whose `jcr:title` is `foo`. I created a node under `querybuilder` called `propertyConstraints` and added my constraints in the form of nodes below it, as described[here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/developing-reports.html#Query%20Definition/). However, this does not work for me at all.

What is the correct way to add constraints to the querybuildernode? Has anyone tried this?

Also, once I get this working correctly, can I extend this example to return pages of a specific template?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [QueryBuilder API](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/search/querybuilder-api.html)?  Adobe's documentation discusses how to match 1 or more property values.

Comment: hmm.. I suspect the components use queryBuilder API once you define them correctly. I'm having problems defining the component structure itself.

Comment: ah, I evaluated the CQ Reports a long time ago, and it didn't meet my needs at the time.  But I like breaking things down into smaller steps, including just figuring how to build a single query to find the data I am looking for.  Once the query is debugged, you could add it to your report.

Answer (score 0):

Create a node `propertyConstraints` under `queryBuilder` of type `nt:unstructured`

create another node under `propertyConstraints` with any name.

Add properties to this node :

```
name String jcr:title 
value String foo
```